# Как получить попарно сгруппированные дубликатные строки pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

Имеется датасет https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/student+performance, в котором некоторые из учеников посещали сразу 2 предмета (а значит у них уникален id и некоторые другие поля, связанные с определенным предметом, но одинаковы поля общ. информации). Нужно найти таких учеников, и сравнить их связанные с определенным предметом поля. Нашел метод `df.duplicated`, и выбрал данные с помощью `df[df.duplicated([неуникальные колонки],keep=False)]`, но это выводит просто список всех дубликатов, а мне хотелось чтобы они выводились попарно(ну или как нибудь, чтобы их сравнить). Что можно сделать?

Comment: приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой (5-10 строк), но воспроизводимый пример данных (в виде текста/кода/CSV, главное не картинкой) и то, что ожидаете получить на выходе

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)